# How to map dict with list of indexes to new variable

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

So, today I'm struggling with the following situation: I have a dictionary where each key is a cluster number, and each value is a list comprised of the index numbers associated to that cluster:

```
dic={'0':[0,1,2],'1':[3,4,5]}
```

And my DataFrame looks like this:

```
index    col
 0       foo
 1       foo
 2       foo
 3       foo
 4       foo
 5       foo
```

I thought the following would work:

```
df['cluster']=df.index.map(dic)
```

But it maps to the keys and not the values, bringing the following:

```
index    col   cluster
 0       foo   [0,1,2]
 1       foo   [3,4,5]
 2       foo     nan
 3       foo     nan
 4       foo     nan
 5       foo     nan
```

And what I want is:

```
index    col   cluster
 0       foo     0
 1       foo     0
 2       foo     0
 3       foo     1
 4       foo     1
 5       foo     1
```

Is there any other way than reversing my dictionary to map this?

Comment: I think you should just reverse your dictionary.  Why wouldn't you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with flatten your `dict`

```
df.index.map({y : x[0] for x in dic.items() for y in x[1]})
Out[379]: Index(['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'], dtype='object')
#df['cluster']=df.index.map({y : x[0] for x in dic.items() for y in x[1]})
```

Comment: I know this is a dict comprehension but could you explain me a bit what it is doing?

Comment: @JuanC your value is list , and you need create the dict base on value to the key , since map will match the key then pop the value